# How to have two root nodes in forest package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I'm using `forest` to make trees. This package automates the measurements and placements of the nodes (which is great!!) I want a node of a forest-tree to be accommodated in two trees.

Have a look at this code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,1) -- (1,-2) node[below]{a};
    \draw (1,1) -- (3,-2) node[below]{b};
    \draw (1,1) -- (-1,-2) node[below]{c};
    \draw[dotted] (5,1) -- (3,-2);
    \draw (5,1) -- (5,-2) node[below]{d};
    \draw (5,1) -- (7,-2) node[below]{e};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code produces -

[image: 1]

This is exactly what I want. Now let's shift to `forest`. I don't want placement-calculations to come in the picture. I want the above tree to be automated. This is a pseudo-forest code, which I want to make workable. In this code there are two trees (which itself is an alien thing for `forest`) & it has one ambiguous node occurring in both of them. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        [[c]
        [a]
        {b}%Special brackets to have this node in both the trees
        ]%This bracket should end the first tree

        [%This bracket should start a new tree
        {b}%Special brackets to have this node in both the trees
        [d]
        [e]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

PS - If possible I also want the dotted line, but it is absolutely optional.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Multi-rooted Tree-like Structures and Nodes with Multiple Parents in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109). Since multidominant trees aren't formally trees, tree drawing packages can't deal with them automatically.

Comment: Thanks this helped me, I understand that tree drawing packages are not meant to draw such structures, but is it really hard to think of this automation? I mean if it is possible to accommodate such changes by tweaking our formalism a bit, won't it be more productive?

Comment: Also this is not helpful for two trees in one environment.

Comment: Well one problem is that you can't represent them with a nested bracketed structure, so the first problem would be to figure out a syntax that would allow you to specify the multidominance.  For the two trees problem you can just make one tree with empty branches and root node dominating the two (sub-)trees.

Comment: How to generate empty branches?

Comment: TikZ is not bad at all: `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\x{1} \def\y{1.5}
\path
(0,0) coordinate (B)
(\x,0) coordinate (D)
+(\x,0) coordinate (E)
+(0,\y) coordinate (R)
(-\x,0) coordinate (A)
+(-\x,0) coordinate (C)
+(0,\y) coordinate (L);
\draw[dotted] (R)--(B);
\draw (R)--(D) (R)--(E) (L)--(A) (L)--(B) (L)--(C);
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D,E}
\path (\p) node[below]{\p};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5):

Mutlidominant trees aren't trees, so there is no good way to automate them with tree drawing packages like `forest` or `tikz-qtree`. But there are ways to create the same effect manually (which I understand is not what you would like).  Here's a sample. The second tree is more symmetrical, but at greater complexity since it involves a phantom third centre node to get the shared node aligned properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[,phantom [A [B ][C,name=C]] [D,name=D [,phantom][F]]]
\draw[dotted] (C.north) -- (D.south);
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}where n children=0{tier=T}{}
[,phantom [A,name=A [B, ][,phantom]][,phantom [C,name=C ]][D,name=D [,phantom][F]]]
\draw (C.north) -- (A.south);
\draw[dotted] (C.north) -- (D.south);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]